# Extracting edge information from network in python

Tags: python, networkx, network-analysis

i have the following network:

```
net = nx.Graph()
node_list = ["Gur","Qing","Samantha","Jorge","Lakshmi","Jack","John","Jill"]
edge_list = [("Gur","Qing",{"source":"work"}),
         ("Gur","Jorge", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","Qing", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Qing", {"source":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Lakshmi", {"source":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Samantha",{"source":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","John", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Lakshmi","Jack", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Jill", {"source":"charity"}),
        ("Jill","John",{"source":"family"})]
net.add_nodes_from(nodes)
net.add_edges_from(edges)
```

In this network every person is a node and in this nodes are all connected with each other based in a type of relationship. The relationships that connect the nodes are the edges in this case.

What i need to do is extract the relationship information contained in the edges in order to create a function that given a person name and a relationship type, tells to which other people is connected based on the the specified relationship type.

I'm using the `networkx` package in python to perform this task. Since i'm totally new to networks this confuses me a bit so i will appreciate any suggestions on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to create a new graph only containing the edges that match the given "source", e.g. for "family":

```
family = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in net.edges(data=True) if d["source"]=="family"])
```

You can then use

```
list(nx.bfs_tree(family, "Gur"))
```

To get the complete family of Gur

Comment: Hey @M. Spiller, thanks a lot for your answer, it helped :) I still have one doubt i would like to share with you. I've built the following function:
(the function is split in the next 2 comments, as i didn't know how to workaround the character limitations)

Comment: `def relationships(graph,node,relationship):
   
    for i in graph, node, relationship:
        if relationship == 'family':
            family = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in graph.edges(data=True) if d["source"]=="family"])
            print(list(nx.bfs_tree(family, node)))
        if relationship == 'work':
            work = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in graph.edges(data=True) if d["source"]=="work"])
            print(list(nx.bfs_tree(work, node)))
        if relationship == 'charity':`

Comment: `charity = nx.Graph([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in graph.edges(data=True) if d["source"]=="charity"])
            print(list(nx.bfs_tree(charity, node)))`

Comment: the problem is that when i try to get this working, it works sometimes only. When i input any person name and any relationship type i find that when that person i input has the relationship type i want to search for it returns the list containing all the other people with the same relationship, so that's ok. 

But if the person name i give is not connected with the relationship type i'm searching, i get the following error:

`KeyError: 'Samantha'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NetworkXError: The node Samantha is not in the graph.`

Comment: Is there a possible way to fix this? or some workaround or something to avoid this error to happen?

Thanks again in advance ;)

Comment: family.has_node("Samantha") will return True iff the node is in the graph.

Comment: yeah i got that. Would it be a way to keep all the nodes in the same graph while getting relationships contained on the edges so i don't get that error?

Comment: Well, you could, but that would make the searching more complicated.
I would say, you should still check for existence of a node before. Your function may be called with a name that is not in the node at all.